# Transfer function in a 2L2C circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, impedance, kirchhoffs-laws

I have to find the transfer function of the following circuit (AC, sinusoidal), using complex numbers, Kirchoff point rule with potentials or Millman's theorem.

[image]

The transfer function is \$\underline{H}=\frac{\underline{i_1}}{\underline{u}}\$ .

Here is what I did for now. Schematic using complex impedances:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsM9ws.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Then we have :
\$-(V_B-V_A)\frac{1}{Z_L+Z_C}-(V_B-V_A)\frac{1}{Z_C}+(V_C-V_A)\frac{1}{Z_L}+u(t)\times i_1=0\$
*^-- False, check in comments for the right one*

But what to do now, how to find i1 and u?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do  u have u(t)*I1 in your equation. I think it is not correct.Al Vb should be zero as question already grounds it. Also U should form 2 set of eq.s if using nodal analysis technique.For clarity.

Comment: Alright understood, so \$V_A\frac{1}{Z_L+Z_C}+V_A\frac{1}{Z_C}+(-V_A+u(t))\frac{1}{Z_L}=0\$ would be the accurate equation, right? But then, how to find a second equation using nodal analysis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of seeing the question is that it demands for net conductance of the circuit. Which is inverse of net impedance offered by the circuit u/i1.
As i1 signifies net current drawn by ckt.
The following explanation is based on that methodology.
I assume you have to find transfer function of the=is ckt.
One simple method might be.

- Replace Z by Laplace equivalents in circuit.
- Find impedence(net) of the circuit.
- Znet = (sL)+inv(sC + inv(sL + 1/sC)) which is u/i1
- Take inverse and you have your answer.

Just to warn nodal might go slightly long. Second is just adaptation of a visible fact(not too much of ideal nodal analysis)   it is  use (u-Va)/zl = i1 . Then you find Va interms of Z and u replace  it in this second eq. And then u should have ur answer. Hop this ans satisfies your query.